# How to get the Outlook mail item's size?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

'm writing an Outlook Add-in for Outlook 2007. This is a VSTO 3.0 , C# add-in. I capture the send event in the add-in and then check some of the Email properties (Which is being sent out) and based on that display some alert.

When I try to get the total size of email using mailItem.Size, it always returns 0 while the actual size of email is not 0. And if I save the email (mailitem.Save()) then mailItem.Size returns the correct size of the mail.
Does any one know about reason behind this behavior . Is there any otherway to get the email size ?

Comment: Before you save the item it is in memory. After you save it, it is persisted to MAPI storage.

Answer (score 2):

yes, this is the default behavior in Outlook.
I suggest you save it (`MailItem.Save`) before you send it. 
Saving the email will place it in the drafts folder...but who cares because you will now check its size (`MailItem.Size`) and send it (`MailItem.Send`).

Answer (score 1):

> > > Does any one know about reason behind this behavior . Is there any otherway to get the email size ?

AFAIK, This is the default behavior in Outlook. You cannot get the size till the time you save/send it.

You can however check for the Attachment size or the Body Length if that helps?